# Does Java always convert addition result into int?

Tags: java, casting, implicit

is it true that java converts primitive Type addition (like byte+short) results into integers?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are talking about [promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).  Its not as simple as always promoting to an int.  [Section 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) talks about primitive widening in detail, but here are a few guidelines:

- If the result is assigned to a variable then it will be promoted to the type of the variable (if possible)
- A more limited type will be promoted to the more expansive type
- A result can be promoted if it is likely to be larger than the type will handle

Like I said this is a simplification of the actual rules, but in general Java does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following sections of the Java Language Specification (JLS) are applicable:

Section 5.6 Numeric Promotions) "Numeric promotion is applied to the operands of an arithmetic operator"

Section 5.6.2.2 Binary Numeric Promotion) "...If either operand is of type double...long...float...Otherwise both operands are converted to type int"

So in your example of byte + short, the operands would each first be converted to ints.

To further illustrate:

```
short a = 1;
short b = 2;
short c = a + b;
```

will produce a compile error "required short, found int".
You would need to cast the result of the addition (an int) to a short, like this:

```
short c = (short) (a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about argument promotion and casting concept.
Java can only evaluate the expressions which have values of the same type. for example if you have the expression a = b + c; then a and b and c must have the same type. you now might wonder so how you can add up an integer and a double without anything goes wrong. this is where the concept of type promotion is applied implicitly by Java. in this case your integer variable is implicitly changed to double only for performing your operation (remember the type of your integer variable is not changed only a double copy is made for your expression).

Now the point is that java only uses type promotion implicitly if the data of your variable is not lost. For example if you change integer to double you will not lose any data. but if you want to change let's say a double variable with value 1.2 to integer then you will lose the fraction part. This is where java will not apply type promotion and you need to do type casting manually. Basically what type casting means is to take control over the compiler and telling to compiler that I know I might lose some data in my variable but it is ok and perform the casting for me.
Type promotion and casting occur in expressions and in method calls.
The table below shows the valid promotions which java would do automatically.

**Type         Valid Promotion**

double       None 
float             double 
long           float or double
int              long, float or double
char          int, long, float or double
short         int, long, float or double (but not char)
byte          short, int, long, float or double (but not char)
boolean    None(boolean values are not considered to be numbers in java)